# Redhat 6.4 configured to log Martian packets but is not logging ll header

Tags: linux, redhat, logging, kernel, packet

I am trying to investigate the source of martian packets I have been seeing on several servers connected to the same subnet. The logging of martian packets has been enabled in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

However when viewing the entries in `/var/log/messages` I only see the following for each martian packet:

```
2013-08-26T12:15:03-04:00 hostname kernel: martian destination 0.0.0.0 from 15.16.0.0, dev eth0
```

I would expect to see a second line similar to the following along with this above line:

```
2013-08-26T12:15:03-04:00 hostname kernel: ll header:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:21:5e:de:1b:be:08:06
```

I have been searching but have been unable to determine why the above line is not being logged along with the initial martian packet being logged. Anyone have any ideas?